# "that's all this analysis will tell us is"

Tags: cleft-constructions

*"I don't really have an opinion of whether Steven Avery is innocent or guilty," Spalding says in the piece. "I have more of an opinion of whether I think there's been planted evidence or not and ultimately **that's all this analysis will tell us is whether or not this evidence is planted**."*

Source: http://www.postcrescent.com/story/news/local/steven-avery/2016/10/21/could-swedish-scientist-break-open-avery-case/92459398/

I am a little bit stuck in the bold part of the above sentence. Especialy the part "that's all the analysis will tell us is". Could you please tell me to which part is "is" before "whether" connected? I would understand if this part would be as follows: …all what this analysis will tell us is… But I am not able to parse the original version.

Comment: It should be "all that this analysis will tell us..."

Comment: The cited text isn't really grammatical. The "incorrect" copula repetition of ***that's*** ... ***is whether*** seems similar to when people say *The thing is is that [whatever the thing is].*

Comment: I don't really have an opinion on whether the pleonasm is justified.  I have more of an opinion on whether a pleonasm occurs.  Ultimately, that's all a reasonable analysis will tell us: whether an instance of "is" is redundant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the phrase "that's all" doesn't sound grammatical in the sentence.  The phrase is usually used for saying there's nothing more involved than what you have mentiond.  It's also used for saying that something is completed/finished/what's needed or wanted.  For examples:

I wasn't interrupting. I was just trying to give my suggestion  - that'all.

Do you want anything else? No, thanks, that's all.

Moreover, there should not be the repetition of the copula 'is', as commented by @FumbleFingers. Even if one 'is' dropped, the sentence will not be correct.

The proper phrase to be used is 'all that' instead of that's all, as commented by @Mick.

Answer (score 0):

All strikers are not equally skilled on the pitch. For example, some strikers can shoot accurately and with force only with their dominant foot, and they will sometimes make a clumsy adjustment mid-stride to avoid a shot with the weak foot.  The skill of speakers also varies, and speakers will sometimes make adjustments mid-sentence, analogous to the striker's adjustments during an attack on goal. It isn't pretty football and it isn't pretty speech.

What you have in your sentence is such an adjustment.

> ... ultimately that's all this analysis will tell us is whether or not
>   this evidence is planted.

The speaker  starts out on one foot, as it were:

> **that is all** this analysis will tell us...

which can accept as adjunct an *if*-clause or a *whether*-clause which stands in apposition to **that**:

> ... whether or not this evidence is planted

But the speaker "switches foot" in the heat of the moment and starts the adjunct  with **is**:

> ... **is** whether or not this evidence is planted.

as if he had begun the first clause so:

> **all** this analysis will tell us...

which demands a verb to complete its thought.